# Ошибка сериализации ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Приложение MVVM WPF, в нём имеется `ListBox`, который привязан (Binding) к `ObservableCollection`. Мне нужно, чтобы каждый раз при изменении этого `ListBox` он сериализовался. Для этого написал статический класс:

```
internal static class TaskDataManager
    {
        public static void SaveTaskCollection(ObservableCollection<Task> collection, DateTime date)
        {
            string fileName = Path.Combine(ApplicationPaths.DatesFolder, DateConverter.ConvertToSaveFormat(date));
            using (Stream stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create))
            {
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                formatter.Serialize(stream, collection);
            }
        }
    }
```

К коллекции в конструкторе прописал событие `CollectionChanged`:

```
public ObservableCollection<Task> MondayItems { get; set; }

MondayItems.CollectionChanged += CollectionChanged;

private void CollectionChanged(object? sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TaskDataManager.SaveTaskCollection((ObservableCollection<Task>)sender, FirstDayWeekDate);
}
```

Данный код успешно сериализует коллекцию с 0 либо 1 элементом в ней, но когда событие вызывается с коллекцией из 2 и более элементов строка `formatter.Serialize(stream, collection);` выбрасывает исключение `System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: "Serializing delegates is not supported on this platform."`.

Пробежавшись по интернету и глянув пару похожих проблем ничего не подметил, так как вызваны они там другими факторами, по типу [этого](https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/issues/4832).

Однако если прописать в конструкторе следующий код, коллекция будет сохранятся с любым количеством элементов и ошибка выше воспроизводится не будет:

```
public ViewModelWeek()
        {
            //Генерация трёх элементов для ObservableCollection
            MondayItems = TaskLipsumGenerator.Next(3);

            //Успешное сохранение коллекции
            TaskDataManager.SaveTaskCollection(MondayItems, FirstDayWeekDate);
        }
```

Из оставшегося выходит, что ошибку может вызывать сам `CollectionChanged`, однако каким образом я так и не понял. Буду рад почитать ваши идеи по этому поводу.

Comment: Бинарная сериализация уже давно ушла на покой, этот класс является устаревшим в C#, а если зайти и почитать [документацию](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?view=net-8.0), то прям красную плашку об этом увидите, с ссылкой на [объяснение](https://aka.ms/binaryformatter). Хотите сериализацию - используете что-то более современное и надежное, например JSON, XML, и так далее.

Comment: Что такое `Task`? Есть стандартный тип `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`, возможно у вас конфликт имен, переименуйте класс.

Comment: Спасибо, тогда буду все переделывать под другой формат. На вопрос что такое `Task` это мой собственный класс из 5-ти свойств, конфликта имен нет, так как я не использую `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` но все равно спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо `EvgeniyZ` за подсказку, `XmlSerializer` работает как швейцарские часы, вы очень сильно мне помогли.